# Проверить попадание случайных и заданых пользователем точек в окружность?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Суть вопроса в том, есть задача, попадание точки в окружность, есть массив который рандомно заполняется 15ю координатами, и условие проверяет попадают ли точки в окружность и т.д. Но хотелось бы реализовать чтобы пользователь смог сам ввести координаты(Х,У). Но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что программа ждем пока пользователь введет свои данные и только потом приступает к выполнению. Можно ли как-то реализовать чтобы программа вывела результат проверки рандомных координат, но пользователь видя результат мог ввести свою координату, чтобы она тоже проверилась?

Листинг части кода:

```
uses graphabc;
var
  x,y: array[1..16] of real;
  s:array[1..16] of char;
  i,p,t,w,f:integer;
  z:string;
const
  a=14;
  b=29;
  r=27;
begin
 SetWindowSize(840, 600);
  randomize;
  t:=0;
  w:=10;
  f:=0;

Coordinate.Origin:=new Point(20,120);
  for i:=1 to 15 do 
      begin
 if i=1 then
    begin

     Coordinate.Origin:=new Point(10,110);
       readln(x[1],y[1]);
    end;
        s[i]:=chr(64+i);
        x[i+1]:=(-30+(34+30)*random);
        y[i+1]:=(-35+(34+35)*random);
        writeln(s[i],'(', x[i]:3:0, ';',y[i]:3:0,')');
        if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=-4) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<=round(-b/2)) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<=round(b/2))
        then t:=t+1;
        if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]>r*r) then begin 
           TextOut(65, f, ' - точка за границей окружности');
           f:=f+16;
        end
           else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]=r*r) then begin 
              TextOut(65, f, ' - точка попала на внешнюю границу');
              f:=f+16; 
           end
           else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<-14) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<round(-b/2)) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]=round(b/2))
                   then begin
                        TextOut(65, f, ' - точка попала на внутреннюю границу');
                        f:=f+16;
                        end
                   else begin
                        TextOut(65, f, ' - точка попала за внутреннюю границу');
                        f:=f+16;
                        end
         end;   
     writeln();
     writeln('Всего точек попало: ', t);
     writeln('Всего точек не попало: ', 15-t);
```

Comment: Как Вы думаете, сколько времени займет проверка пятнадцати точек, и успеет ли пользователь что-нибудь ввести, так сказать, "посреди" этой проверки?

Comment: @Igor, простите, я тогда изменю сейчас вопрос, тогда поставим вопрос так: как сделать чтобы пользователь мог после проверки 15 координат, ввести свою координату и проверить ее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создай процедуру, в нее вынеси весь код проверки точки. Параметром для процедуры будет введенная точка. Далее сделай бесконечный цикл `while true do`, в его теле считывай ввод пользователя и вызывай процедуру, передав в нее введенные координаты. Таким образом сможешь вводить сколько угодно координат и проверять их сразу.